# Need help adding a loop to count all hidden sheets or sheets beginning "S."

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops, count

I want to remove the list here by replacing it with some sort of automatic count function which counts either the number of hidden sheets within the workbook or counts all sheets named "S."    (would give the same result so whichever easier)

The goal is to automate the function so "22" is not used as some workbooks have fewer sheets

I've tried a few functions but so far can't integrate the counter into the second part of the code (For ii = 1 to 22)

```
Dim list(22) As Variant> 
list(1) = "S.xxx "
list(2) = "S.xx "
etc 


Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String 
Dim GetFile As Variant 


Workbooks.Open GetFile(i)
With ActiveWorkbook
For ii = 1 To 22
Set ws1 = Sheets.(list(ii))
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(list(ii))
ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells 

Next ii
End with

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: what is `GetFile(i)`?

Comment: it opens up a new file - code is attempting to import data from templates and place it in matched templates in master

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `For Each ... Next` loop ad check the first character of current sheet name:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim GetFile As Variant

' some code to define GetFile...

With Workbooks.Open(GetFile(i)) ' open and reference wanted file
    For Each ws In .Worksheets ' loop through referenced workbook worksheets
        If UCase(Left(ws.name, 1) = "S") Then ' if current worksheet name begins with "S"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.name).UsedRange.Clear ' clear "target" worksheet (i.e. worksheet in ThisWorkbook with the same name) used range
            ws.UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.name).Range("A1") ' copy current worksheet used range to "target" worksheet
        End If
    Next
    .Close
End With
```